# Program compiles but won't run, cannot use constructor

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me why I can't create a new object in my Interactions panel or why this program won't run even though it was compiled?

```
   import java.util.Random;
/**
 * This program allows a user to enter their first and last name
 * and generate a random user id and default password.
 * 
 * @author Brian Drake
 * @version 9/14/11
 */

   public class UserID {

      private String firstName;

      private String lastName;

      private String userId;

      private String password;


      public UserID(String first, String last) {
         Random generator = new Random();

         firstName = first;

         lastName = last;

         userId = first.substring(0, 3) + last.substring(0, 3)
            + generator.nextInt(1) + (generator.nextInt(7) + 3)
            + generator.nextInt(10);

         password = Integer.toString(generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10)
            + generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10)
            + generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10));

      } 

      public String getId() {
         return userId;
      }

      public String getPassword() {
         return password;
      }

      public boolean setPassword(String randomPass) {

         if (password.length() < 6 || password.length() > 6) {
            randomPass = password;

            return false;       
         }

         else {
            password = randomPass;
         }
         return true;
      }

      public void generateNewPassword() {

         Random generator = new Random();

         password = Integer.toString(generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10)
            + generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10)
            + generator.nextInt(10) + generator.nextInt(10));

      }

      public String toString(String first, String last) {
         String output = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
         output += userId + "\n";
         output += password;
         return output;
      }

   }
```

Comment: what the heck is an "interactions panel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class definition of `UserID`, you need to assign parameter values while creating an object (because you didn't create no argument constructor).

```
UserID obj=new UserID("firstName","secondName");
```

Edit:

Apart from the `UserID` class, you have to define another class which contains an entry point - main() method.

```
public class TestMain
{
  public static void main(String []args)
   {
     UserID obj=new UserID("firstName","secondName");
     //Using obj reference variable, you can request to the object for any message.
     System.out.println(obj.getId() + " " + obj.getPassword());
   }
}
```

Comment: where should I add this in at?

Comment: @user951901 May be you need to add an entry point - main method

Answer (score 5):

It won't run because there is no main method

Answer (score 0):

This is not a program.  This is just a class, that's potentially part of a program.  You should have gotten a `NoSuchMethodException` or something similar when you tried to run it.

A program is essentially a class that has a `public static void main(String[] args)` in it.  You'll need to add one if you want to make this thing run on its own (as opposed to just being a component used by some other code).  Note that Java will call this method to run your program, so it also needs to do something useful.  Like, say, create a UserID and display it or something.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create objects of `UserID` class. Program execution entry point in `Java` is its `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```